# How to define different layouts for different routes in Next.js inside the pages folder?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I would like to implement layout-based routing in my `pages` directory. I am looking for a way to use something similar to the `_app.tsx` file, but only for the files inside a specific folder.

This would function similarly to the Remix routing style, where there is a folder, such as `panel` and a file called `panel.tsx` that wraps the files inside the "panel" folder with a layout.

How can I achieve something similar in the Next.js `pages` directory?

What I want:

```
pages/
      panel/
            index.tsx
            dashboard.tsx
      panel.tsx
```

The `panel.tsx` file will function like a layout in new `app` directory basically i want to find a way to wrap around files inside a folder just exactly like how Remix does it or the new `app` directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are talking about is called [Per-Page Layouts](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/layouts#per-page-layouts) in Next.js. And it works as follow, as you can read on the doc:

> If you need multiple layouts, you can add a property `getLayout` to your page, allowing you to return a React component for the layout. This allows you to define the layout on a per-page basis. Since we're returning a function, we can have complex nested layouts if desired.

```
// pages/index.js

import Layout from '../components/layout'
import NestedLayout from '../components/nested-layout'

export default function Page() {
  return (
    /** Your content */
  )
}

Page.getLayout = function getLayout(page) {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <NestedLayout>{page}</NestedLayout>
    </Layout>
  )
}
```

```
// pages/_app.js

export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  // Use the layout defined at the page level, if available
  const getLayout = Component.getLayout || ((page) => page)

  return getLayout(<Component {...pageProps} />)
}
```

The above is for the `/` page, but the logic is the same for any route. Just adapt your imports and layouts names, and you will be good to go.

Comment: Thank you this is working, although it's not like fully the same as i wanted but i can achieve what i wanted using this. Isn't this just wrapping the component around a layout. i mean i think we can achieve the same result with just wrapping the component inside a Layout component for example.